# i am using 4 for lopp , 2 are working correct rest 2 are showing issue 3 and 4 loop are showing invalid answer

Tags: c, loops

i am using 4 for lopp , 2 are working correct rest 2 are showing issue 3 and 4 loop are showing invalid answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  // your code goes here
  int n,arr[n],i,l=0,m=0,u=0,d=0;

  printf("enter the value of n");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  arr[0]=0;

  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    arr[i+1]=arr[i]+10;
  }

  printf("%d",arr[3]);

  for(i=1;i<=n;i=i+4) {
    l=arr[i]+l;
  }

  for(i=2;i<=n;i=i+4) {
    u=arr[i]+u;
  }

  for(i=3;i<=n;i=i+4) {
    m=arr[i]+m;
  }

  /* for(i=4;i<=n;i=i+4) { d=arr[i]+d; } */

  printf("\n%d\n",l);
  printf("%d\n",u);
  printf("%d\n",m);
  printf("%d\n",d);

  return 0;
}
```

answer in negative

Comment: You're potentially exceeding top-end array boundaries in every single one of those loops. And `n` is indeterminate when `arr[n]` is declared anyway, so that too, is wrong. Move the declaration of `arr[n]` *after* you read `n` from stdin (which you should be checking for success and in-range validity, but that's another separate issue).

Comment: You'll also should hard-set *just* `arr[0] = 0;` after the decl once it's moved.

Comment: [mcve][mcve][mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Among the things wrong in this code

- Your decl of `arr[n]` is based on an *indeterminate* `n` value. The array doesn't magically resize when you read `n` later in your program. `n` has to be known before the `arr` decl.
- Your loop limits are potentially out of range (and *definitely* with the first loop).
- The `scanf` call to populate `n` isn't checked for successful stdin input. Never assume your IO works, *especially* the 'I' in IO.

Just fixing those:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, l = 0, m = 0, u = 0, d = 0;

    printf("enter the value of n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0)
    {
        int arr[n];
        arr[0] = 0;

        for (i = 0; i<(n - 1); i++) {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i] + 10;
        }

        printf("%d", arr[3]);

        for (i = 1; i < n; i += 4) {
            l = arr[i] + l;
        }

        for (i = 2; i < n; i += 4) {
            u = arr[i] + u;
        }

        for (i = 3; i < n; i += 4) {
            m = arr[i] + m;
        }

        printf("\n%d\n", l);
        printf("%d\n", u);
        printf("%d\n", m);
        printf("%d\n", d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[See it live on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/t6zxlR)